# How to extend identity user properties with a select box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-identity-2

I have very little experience with razor and mvc controllers. I would like to add a dropdown box in my registration view. I have tried some different things from some examples online but I do not know how to access the class i need through the application user. I want to add a list of companies. I really got lost on going through the account viewmodels. i removed the relationship from the company class because i had to clean it up. not sure what is needed with this. a user can only have one company.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> 
        GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager
            .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
```

Company Class

```
 public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

Account View model

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "CompanyName")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Property for the options
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompanyOptions(string selected)
    {
        //This is just static - get it from somewhere else (database?)
        return new List<SelectListItem>{ 
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Company 1", Value = "1", Selected = selected.Equals("1") },
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Company 2", Value = "2", Selected = selected.Equals("2") }
         };
    }
}
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
 <div class="col-md-10">
   @Html.DropDownFor(m => m.CompanyId, Model.CompanyOptions(Model.CompanyId), null)
  </div>
```

Error Message

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 
>   Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownFor' and no extension method 'DropDownFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Source Error:
>   Line 41:                                             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
>   Line 42:                                             
>   Line 43:                                                 @Html.DropDownFor(m => m.CompanyId, Model.CompanyOptions(Model.CompanyId), null)
>   Line 44:                                             
>   Line 45:                                         
>   Blockquote

new error

> Compiler Error Message: CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary)' and 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, string)'

UserAdmin Controller

```
// GET: /Users/Create
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
    {
        //Get the list of Roles
        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Name", "Name");
        return View();
    }
 // POST: /Users/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(RegisterViewModel userViewModel, params string[] selectedRoles)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser 
            {
                UserName = userViewModel.UserName,
                Email = userViewModel.Email,
                CompanyId = userViewModel.CompanyId,
                Name = userViewModel.Name
            };


                user.UserName = userViewModel.UserName;
                user.Email = userViewModel.Email;
                user.CompanyId = userViewModel.CompanyId;
                user.Name = userViewModel.Name;

            // Then create:
            var adminresult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, userViewModel.Password);

            //Add User to the selected Roles 
            if (adminresult.Succeeded)
            {
                if (selectedRoles != null)
                {
                    var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, selectedRoles);
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Name", "Name");
                        return View();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", adminresult.Errors.First());
                ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Name", "Name");
                return View();

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Name", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

Account Controller

```
// GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }
// POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, CompanyId = model.CompanyId, Name = model.Name };


            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", 
                    new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, 
                    "Confirm your account", 
                    "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" 
                    + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
                return View("DisplayEmail");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Register View Model

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "CompanyName")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Property for the options
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompanyOptions(int selected)
    {
        //This is just static - get it from somewhere else (database?)
        return new List<SelectListItem>{ 
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Company 1", Value = "1", Selected = selected.Equals("1") },
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Company 2", Value = "2", Selected = selected.Equals("2") }
         };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second error message is as a result of using `null` for the 3rd parameter of `DropDownListFor()`. The call is ambiguous because the is an overload that accepts `string labelOption` and one that accepts `object htmlAttributes`

Remove the 3rd parameter (or if you want an option label, make it a `string`, for example `string.Empty`, or `"-Please select-"`)

You also should not set the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem`. `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyId, ...` is binding to property `CompanyId` so if the value of `CompanyId` matches the value of one of the options, then that option will be selected (in your code above, if `CompanyId=2`, then the second option will be selected). The value of the `Selected` property is ignored. Instead, change `CompanyOptions` to a property

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompanyOptions { get; set; }
```

and in the controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel();
  model.CompanyId = 2; // set this if you want to display a specific company
  ConfigureViewModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Create(RegisterViewModel model)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
  // Save and redirect
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(RegisterViewModel model)
{
  model.CompanyOptions = new List<SelectListItem>()
  {
    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Company 1", Value = "1" },
    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Company 2", Value = "2" }
  };
}
```

If your access the companies from a database, its more likely to be

```
model.CompanyOptions = new SelectList(db.Companies, "ID", "Name")
```

Comment: ok looks great. i do need some help though. I am using a seed project that included user roles, and UserAdmin control. So there is some more controllers that I am used to. can you help placing your code. I updated my post

Comment: I don't understand you comment. What problem are you having? Your `Create()` method looks odd - other than your setting the values of `user` twice, what is `params string[] selectedRoles`? Why is `selectedRoles` not a property of the view model, how are you rendering controls for `selectedRoles`? And you edit just repeats exactly (I think) the `RegisterViewModel` you had in the original so I'm a little confused. In any case, it does not seem to be related to your original question or the error you were getting, so it should be a new question

Comment: thats the issue, it was a seed project that i used becuase it had userroles and user management ready to go. I really dont understand about how it is setup. I am only used to having a account controller, this has a account controller and a userAdmin controller. So I got a little lost when I was trying to plug your stuff in. I am going to work on it again in a little while. I still plan on giving you credit for your help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a list of companies to your registration model, present that to the user in the view, and then take the selected value and apply it in your post action.

The model:

```
//Property for the options
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompanyOptions(string selected)
{
    //This is just static - get it from somewhere else (database?)
    return new List<SelectListItem>{ 
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Company 1", Value = "1", Selected = selected.Equals("1") },
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Company 2", Value = "2", Selected = selected.Equals("2") }
    };
}
```

Now we can render this to the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyId, Model.CompanyOptions(Model.CompanyId), null)
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can use the `CompanyId` property on the model in the `Register` action.

Comment: no worries, but getting this now The best overloaded method match for 'TransparentEnergy.Models.RegisterViewModel.CompanyOptions(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Try changing the argument from a string to an int.